# React Relay and server side rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relayjs, isomorphic-relay

I've been working on an isomorphic app built with react and I've read about using `Relay.js` and `GraphQL` for client-server interactions.
I've been wondering, is there any special set up or things to keep in mind when using `Relay.js`, when using react's server side rendering & isomorphic app development in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Relay currently has no "out of the box" solution for isomorphic application.
There's still a solution though:

- [`isomorphic-relay`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-relay): npm package with a very detailed documentation on how to integrate with it easily.
- [`isomorphic-relay-router`](https://github.com/denvned/isomorphic-relay-router): npm package that adds server side rendering support to `react-router-relay` using `isomorphic-relay`.

For my understanding, adding server side rendering is in the works, but with no ETA.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use babel to transform relay to graphql queries.
2. Dataloader from facebook or similar is needed for caching.
3. Your data model need to be fully normalised to work with above.
4. Try avoiding JSON as column type, difficult to describe in graphql
5. Use [graphiql](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql) as [browser plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromeiql/fkkiamalmpiidkljmicmjfbieiclmeij) or standalone